# Hitting a wall with nginx SSL forwarding

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, nginx, jitsi

I have an ningx reverse proxy server (running on a VM). I need it to forward 443 traffic from a subdomain to another VM running Jitsi (which requires its own installation of nginx with ssl certificate validation to run).

I'm confused about how this is supposed to work.  I've been reading for the past week and I'm worried it's over my head until someone can explain it to me, for which I'd be very grateful!

https://meet.example.com -> a dynamic dns domain --> nginx VM --> jitsi VM also running nginx.

I'm unclear on which machine is supposed to set up the certificate.  Is it both VMs? Is it just one or the other?

I have an 80 port forwarding to set up just to try and validate the certificate. Here's everything I was playing with.  I feel like I'm in over my head!

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name meet.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.33; # Jitsi server w/ nginx
    }

}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    server_name www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;
    include snippets/ssl.conf;
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;

    include snippets/ssl.conf;
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  https://192.168.1.43:443; # this goes someplace else
    }
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name meet.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass       https://192.168.1.33; # Jitsi server w/ nginx
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar setup to you that I finally got working.

I have two VM's one (Web VM) is acting as a reverse proxy for the Jitsi VM.

Here is what I have for my Web VM:

Web VM:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name jitsimeet.xxx.xxx;

    ssl_certificate      /usr/local/etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /usr/local/etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log    /var/log/nginx/jitsimeet.access.log;

    client_max_body_size  50m;

    location / {   
    #insufficient        
    #proxy_pass          https://192.168.xxx.xxx:4444;
    #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

    #Courtesy of: https://mangolassi.it/topic/18400/anyone-using-jitsi-behind-nginx
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_pass https://192.168.xxx.xxx:4444/;
    proxy_read_timeout 90;

}
```

The port is 4444 because if you look at the jitsi nginx install, it likely has the following config file:

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/jitsimeet.xxx.xxx.conf
```

which shows you that it's listening to port 4444:

```
server {
    listen 4444 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:4444 ssl http2;
    server_name jitsimeet.xxx.xxx;
    ....
```

Be sure to open up the firewall for port 4444 on the Jitsi system (this had me for a while):

```
ufw allow 4444
```

If it fails, attempt to do some testing with CURL:

```
curl --insecure https://192.168.xxx.xxx:443
```

Confirm that you can get the Jitsi Page or some useful error message.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SuperUser. Kinda rude to roll back my edit. I was just trying to be helpful. But alright.

Comment: thank you! i'm testing this out now

Comment: the thing i'm a little confused about is... how do you validate the certificate for the jitsi server?  does the Site VM or the Jitsi VM need to validate with LetsEncrypt?

Comment: @0xC0000022L sorry about that. If you look at the history of updates, you must have caught me right as I was making an update for the nginx reverse proxy portion. I discovered my original answer was inadequate with only proxy_pass and the original set_header. I made further updates to mirror your fixes.

Comment: @russellaugust, with a LetsEncrypt cert, the root certificate should already be on the Jitsi server, so no further validation on your end is required. Having a self-signed certificate will result in needing to make additional tweaks. I have no further details on that as I didn't want to go down that road.

Comment: Finally got this working after some stumbling.  this filled in the last bits i needed! Thank you!